# The zero function is integrable in $\pmb{ANY}$ set and its integral is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration

> **Definition** 1
>
> Let $Q$ a rectangle; let $f:Q\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a bounded function. As $P$ ranges over all partitions of $Q$, define
> $$
> \underline{\int_Q}f:=\underset{P}\sup\{L(f,P)\}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\overline{\int_Q}f:=\underset{P}\inf\{U(f,P)\}.
> $$
> These numbers are called the lower integral and upper integral, respectively, of $f$ over $Q$.
>
> **Theorem** 2
>
> Let $Q$ be a rectangle; let $f:Q\rightarrow\Bbb R$ a bounded function. Then
> $$
> \underline{\int_Q}f\le\overline{\int_Q}f;
> $$
> equality holds if and only if given $\epsilon>0$, there exist a corresponding partition $P$ of $Q$ for which
> $$
> U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon
> $$
>
> **Definition** 3
>
> Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$; let $f:S\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a bounded function. Define $f_S:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ by the equation
> $$
> f_S(x):=\begin{cases}f(x),\,\,\,\text{for}\,\,\,x\in S\\0,\,\,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
> $$
> Choose a rectangle $Q$ containing $S$. We define the integral of $f$ over $S$ by the equation
> $$
> \int_S f:=\int_Q f_S
> $$
> provided the latter integral exists.
>
> **Lemma** 4
>
> Let $Q$ and $Q'$ be two rectangles in $\Bbb R^n$. If $f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow R$ is a bounded function that vanishes outside $Q\cap Q'$, then
> $$
> \int_Q f=\int_{Q'} f;
> $$
> one integral exists if and only if the other does.

So using the preceding results I want prove the following two things.

**Lemma**

The zero function $\pmb{0}$ is integrable in any rectangle $Q$ and is integral is zero.

*Proof*. So if $P$ is a partition of $Q$ then clearly
$$
m_R(\pmb{0})\le 0\le M_R(\pmb{0})
$$
for any subrectangle $R$. So if
$$
m_R(\pmb{0})<0<M_R(\pmb{0})
$$
for some rectangle $R$ then by properties of the infimum and supremum for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $x,y\in Q$ such that
$$
0=\pmb{0}(x)<m_R(\pmb{0})+\epsilon\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, 0=\pmb{0}(y)>M_R(\pmb{0})-\epsilon
$$
and clearly this is impossible. So we conlcude that
$$
L(f,P)=0=U(f,P)
$$
for any partition $P$ of $Q$ so that the positive and negative number are respectively an upper bound of $\{L(f,P)\}$ and a lower bound of $\{U(f,P)\}$ so that there exist the lower integral and the upper integral of $\pmb 0$ function. So for any $\epsilon>0$ then
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=0<\epsilon
$$
for any partition $P$ so that by the  theorem 2 we conclude that $\pmb{0}$ is integrable over $Q$.  Now if $\int_Q\pmb{0}\neq 0$ then $\underset{P}\sup\{L(f,P)\}>0$ so that by the property of supremum for any $\epsilon\in\big(0,\underset{P}\sup\{L(f,P)\}\big)$ there exist a partition $P$ such that
$$
0<\underset{P}\sup\{L(f,P)\}-\epsilon<L(f,P)=0
$$
and this is clearly impossible. So the corollary holds.

**Theorem**

If $S$ is a bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$ then the zero function $\pmb 0$ is there integrable and its integral is zero.

**Proof**. So if $Q$ is a rectangle containing $S$ then the function $0_S$ fulfills the hypothesis of the preceding lemma so that with the **same** argument (**formally it would be necessary to repeat it!**) it is possible to prove that $0_S$ is integrable over $Q$ and its integral is zero thus the theorem holds.

So I ask if the statement of the question is true and in particular if the proof I gave is correct: I realise that this could be a trivial result but unfortunately I see that never text prove it although it is used in many proofs. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Yes, you are right. By your definitions it is true. But some textbooks like to require $\partial S$ to be jordan measurable with zero measure. It is all about how to construct the theory. For the Lebesgue integral, for example, it is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the result is intuitively obvious it is easy to give a proof with true statements that are not fully justified.  If your objective is to be really precise, then I would make the following improvements.

(1) Given $m_R(\pmb{0})\le 0\le M_R(\pmb{0})$ and assuming that $m_R(\pmb{0})< 0\ < M_R(\pmb{0})$ you assert that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $x,y \in Q$ such that

$$0=\pmb{0}(x)<m_R(\pmb{0})+\epsilon\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, 0=\pmb{0}(y)>M_R(\pmb{0})-\epsilon$$

and this is clearly is impossible.  As it may hold for some $\epsilon $, produce a specific example where it fails to hold.  For example, with $\epsilon = -m_R(\mathbf{0})/2 > 0$ we get the contradiction $0=\pmb{0}(x)<m_R(\pmb{0})/2 <0$.

(2) The proof that $\int_Q \mathbf{0} = 0$ is indirect and a little cumbersome.  Why not simply say that for all $P$ we have

$$0 = L(f,P) \leqslant \int_Q \mathbf{0} \leqslant U(f,P) = 0$$

(3) A minor detail is in proving that $\int_S \mathbb{0} =0 $ for any bounded set $S$, you are starting with the definition

$$\int_S \mathbb{0} := \int_Q\mathbb{0}_S,$$

where $Q$ can be any rectangle containing $S$.  I would add that $\mathbf{0}_S$ is everywhere continuous and, therefore,  integrable on $Q$ regardless of the content of boundary $\partial S$.

Comment: But you did a very good job overall.

Comment: Perhaps could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789359/if-fx-gx-for-any-x-in-s-and-f-is-integrable-over-s-then-g-is-there) too?